# J2ME TextField Exception

Tags: java, java-me, textfield, numeric, lcdui

When I instantiate a textField, I have a number in it that I want to be the default text.  The problem is, I can't seem to be able to place that value into the textfield without getting an error.  The strange thing about it is that the same TextField is what I use to set the value of the variable containing the number.

```
TextField myTF = new TextField("Number", value, 10, TextField.NUMERIC);
```

When I run this code, I receive an exception stating that value doesn't match the constraints of TextField.NUMERIC.  However, when I check the vale of the value of the variable, I get the following output:

```
value          = 1234567890
value.length() = 10
```

The value is set by the same TextField, saved to the phone that I am working on, and when loaded from the phone's settings, throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a JVM bug. If a `TextField` returned a string, it must be able to accept it. The only thing I can advice is to play a bit with the size of the field or the constraints. You haven't specified the device you are using, there could be some new firmwares for it with bugfixes.

Answer (score 1):

a potential workaround to your problem could be to instantiate the field with a null value and then set the text afterwards.

```
TextField myTF = new TextField("Number", null, 10, TextField.NUMERIC);
myTF.setString(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.  The cellphone is trying to store the field value as an int, and the maximum int value is (2^31) - 1 = 2,147,483,647, which is one digit short of what you (and me) need.  Workaround, make your field of type text and set a charset of IS_LATIN_DIGITS. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is you try it

```
String str=""+value;
TextField myTF = new TextField("Number",str,10,TextField.NUMERIC);
```